# Como denunciar suspeitas manipulações para ganhos de pontuação?

Tags: debate, suporte

Em resumo geral, o sistema desta comunidade funciona da seguinte forma: O usuário ganha pontos por **"participação ativa"** na comunidade de alguma forma e a cada quantidade de pontuação é liberada ações a este usuário, os famosos [privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Sou novo na comunidade e possuo apenas algumas semanas de participação ativa na mesma, porém já percebi a sede de muitos usuários em ganhar pontuação e os mesmos encontram alguma forma de se fazer o seguinte:

- **Manipular algum tipo de votação nas Perguntas e Respostas**
- **Editar e Aceitar edições "esdrúxula"**

**Entre diversas outras formas!**

Atualmente acabei de passar por uma dessas situações, no caso a segunda opção citada acima, onde eu fiz uma edição á uma pergunta e a mesma foi aceita, passando-se alguns minutos outro usuário denominado [@epx](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4612/epx) fez uma edição ridícula em minha opinião a qual foi:

- **Adicionar Espaços em Branco em uma parte do Código**

Não posso acusar e nem afirmar, porém ao adentrar no perfil deste usuário percebi que o mesmo possui uma reputação de 6.237 pontos em 172 respostas, e chega á ser cômico, pois o mesmo nem possui perguntas na comunidade. Com esta pequena análise eu tiro algumas conclusões de que este usuário foi criado para ajudar o seu perfil original de alguma forma.

Agora vamos as perguntas referentes a este assunto:

- **a) A comunidade não possui um local onde podemos denunciar essas possíveis manipulações?**
- **b) Neste caso que eu passei** ([link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/386845/revisions))**, é correto este usuário editar e até mesmo aprovar a própria edição? E ainda mais uma edição ridícula..**

Comment: O usuário em questão tem mais de 2000 pontos, então as edições dele não passam mais por aprovação e ele não ganha pontos por editar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: @hkotsubo correto, mas não deveria ter um novo conceito para o mesmo? Levando em consideração a situação a qual acabei de passar neste exato momento? O link do acontecido está ali na pergunta, observe e me diz o que você acha.

Comment: Vc está dizendo que ele de alguma maneira manipulou o sistema, criando outra conta para aprovar as próprias edições e ganhar pontos. Mas ele não ganha mais pontos por edição, e elas não precisam mais ser aprovadas, pq ele já tem mais de 2000 pontos, então essas suspeitas/acusações não fazem sentido. A única coisa que podemos questionar é a qualidade e utilidade da edição

Comment: @hkotsubo Concordo com o seu ponto de vista. Mas veja só, podemos muito bem ter "um perfil original" e ter diversos perfis **"fakers"**. Para eu ganhar pontos em meu perfil original ao fazer alguma pergunta, edição entre outros eu posso utilizar os meus perfis **"fakers"** para pontuar as minhas perguntas, respostas, aprovar edições, mas para isto eu preciso que esses perfis **"fakers"** tenham pontuação para poder utilizar diversas ações. Não acha que deveria ter algum tipo de verificação de perfil para poder ter certos privilégios ? Em relação á esta edição, o que você acha sobre a mesma ?

Comment: De qualquer forma, se vc suspeita das atitudes de algum usuário, basta sinalizar a pergunta escolhendo a opção  "precisa da atenção dos moderadores", e explicando o motivo...

Comment: @hkotsubo este tipo de ação é referente quando o usuário é o dono da pergunta, ou esta ação é referente como um todo, por exemplo: À quem fez edições, comentários entre outros?

Comment: Vc pode sinalizar uma pergunta na qual o usuário "suspeito" tem alguma participação, seja ele o autor ou alguém que editou, comentou ou respondeu. Basta ser bem claro no campo de texto onde vc coloca os detalhes. Sobre "fakes": https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57682/401803

Comment: Sobre a edição em si, é complicado pq em Python a indentação pode ser a causa do erro e corrigindo-a vc pode descaracterizar a pergunta. Mas não parece ser o caso desta pergunta...

Comment: Python é uma exceção a todas (ou quase) linguagens na comunidade justamente por gerenciar os blocos lógicos conforme a indentação. Corrigir isso na pergunta pode, ou não, ter consequências. Há perguntas que, se a pessoa tem um pouco de familiaridade com a linguagem, é possível perceber que foi somente uma falha ao escrever a pergunta, possivelmente por desconhecer como funciona o editor do site e corrigir a indentação será muito bem-vinda; mas em muitos outros não fica claro o problema, podendo ser exatamente a indentação errada e corrigí-la iria mascará-lo na pergunta.

Comment: No geral, recomenda-se que seja evitado alterar linhas de código em uma edição para não correr riscos. Viu que pode estar errado? Comente solicitando que o autor corrija. Há, claro, exceções, em que a edição realmente melhora a legibilidade e não tem porque recusar, mas é necessário ter a certeza que isso não alterou o código. Para Python, quase sempre o ideal é recusar.

Comment: Eu acabei de fazer uma análise e quase cometi a mesma situação que foi descrita e posso afirmar que é um erro legitimo e qualquer analista pode vir a cometer. No momento da análise são mostrados 2 botões um com as modificações e outro com o resultado dependendo de qual estiver selecionado não dá uma real impressão das modificações então a tendencia é rejeitar as modificações e editar.
Agora não entendi essa parte de ser cômico por não apresentar perguntas e possuir reputação. Até o momento eu tenho 4 perguntas 143 respostas e 535 comentários, sou novato, isso me torna um fake?

Answer (score 11):

Se tiver suspeita de irregularidades em votação pode sinalizar alguma postagem dessa pessoa que dá um indício que esteja fazendo e a moderação fará uma análise disto. Infelizmente não tem um meio mais específico para isto.

Algumas pessoas usam comentários para avisar sobre isto. A pessoa escolhe um local meio aleatório e comenta para um moderador olhar, logo depois apaga o comentário. Não é a melhor forma, mas se usada com parcimônia e com boa intenção é aceitável.

Existem algumas formas mais informais e menos ortodoxas para avisar a moderação e que prefiro não dizer pra não dar ideia :)

Quanto a conta exposta não tem qualquer indício de manipulação para obter a reputação. Inclusive algumas das afirmações nem fazem sentido.

Só para ter ideia, analisando a sua conta tem mais indícios que poderá ter manipulações que a conta apresentada como possibilidade de fraude. Quero deixar claro que não estou dizendo que sua conta tem manipulação, **não tem**, e obviamente não posso afirmar que o fará no futuro, mas tem um pequeno detalhe que poderia haver suspeita por alguém que não está acostumado ver as estatísticas, coisa mínima mesmo, algo bem abaixo de 1% que poderá ter algo no futuro (tem várias contas com porcentagens bem maiores e sabemos que não tem manipulação, e essa porcentagem que estou dizendo é de percepção e não algo matemático), enquanto que a conta do epx tem zero possibilidade dentro do que o sistema consegue apontar. E só consideramos fraude quando é quase 100% certo.

Então não faça acusações públicas sem ter certeza que aquilo ocorreu.

Quanto a qualidade da edição, concordo que ela não era adequada e já foi solucionado. Mas se ela tivesse resolvido um problema do site não seria ruim e em momento algum a pessoa ganhou pontos por causa disto.

Comment: Faz esse calculo com a minha conta. Eu gostaria de saber qual a minha probabilidade de cometer fraudes futuras na página?

Comment: Não faz sentido fazer isso. Primeiro porque todo mundo vai pedir, segundo porque só ajudará a pessoa cometer fraude, e terceiro n]ao é tão matemático assim, o número postado é anedótico.